# Getting errors in framework files after trying to install new pod

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I've been having a recurring issue that has to do with my pod file and my target swift language version. In the past I have gotten it solved by changing my language version to 4.0 (I think).

What happens is that I update my pod file and then I start getting errors in the framework files that I cannot change because it says they are locked.

I do not understand my pod file and language settings that well which is making it hard to troubleshoot.

I'd like to migrate my frameworks to a newer language version like it recommends, but it says I cannot do that until I make them compile with the previous version.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot or what steps to take to get this all cleared up. Can anyone help?

Here is my podfile

```
target 'DarkhorseDFS' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks



#pod 'RAMAnimatedTabBarController', '~> 4.0'
#pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', :git => 'https://github.com/KelvinJin/XLPagerTabStrip', :branch => 'swift3'

#pod 'BTNavigationDropdownMenu', :git => 'https://github.com/PhamBaTho/BTNavigationDropdownMenu.git', :branch => 'swift-3.0'

pod 'BTNavigationDropdownMenu'
pod 'XLPagerTabStrip'

pod 'SCLAlertView'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'

pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'Kingfisher'
pod 'Tutti'

pod 'Segmentio'
#pod 'PVSwitch'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'Alamofire'

end


target 'DarkhorseDFSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

[image: this is where I'm trying to change my swift language settings.]

I've also tried changing the settings in under 'Target'.

Heres an example of some errors I'm getting, but also many 'name has been changed' errors.

All these frameworks worked before trying to install a new pod. But now I can't get the errors to go away, even when I uninstall!

[image]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You say you're getting errors, it would be helpful if you included what those errors are.

Comment: What are the error? Do you have pods error when you do the cocoapods command? If you use Swift 4, are all the pods you use compatible Swift 4?

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to leave you all hanging. There are many different types of errors, mostly that the names of methods have been changed.. but I cannot update any of them because the files are locked

Comment: I am not sure how to know if all pods are compatable with swift 4, do I have to check the docs for each one?

Comment: Larme, the cocoapods command? Do you mean pod install? - no error there.

Comment: I updated with a photo of some errors.

Comment: Answer: I needed to change my swift language version for each pod individually, not just in build settings.

Comment: I'm kind of late to this party here, but I wanted to stop by and say that you shouldn't be editing the code for a library from a pod. Why are you trying to edit these method names?

Comment: Late but welcome ;-). I wasn't trying to edit the method names. The errors were just telling me that the method names had changed in the new version of swift. I only mentioned they were locked to try to help explain what was going on. Obviously, I didn't do the greatest job. The problem was when I installed a new pod it defaulted my other pods to the wrong language version. I figured out how to change the swift v. for each one manually and was able to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change my swift language version for each pod individually, not just in project build settings.

Click on Pods in the navigator, then the language version can be set in build settings.